# Playing video from internal storage on Android?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, permissions

I have created an application which downloads video files to internal storage. The reason is that I do not want to use the permission for access all files (MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS).

The download works well and a I checked it on a rooted device. The video files are stored here:
/data/user/0/com.xxxx.xxxxx/files/videos/example.mp4

If I try to open the file with the default video player on Android, it says that the video cannot be played. If I copy the same file to the sdcard, it can be played without any problem. So the file seems to be fine.

This is the way how I try to open the file:

```
            File myDir = new File(activity.getFilesDir(),"videos");
            File file = new File(myDir, videoname);
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            Log.e("FILE TO PLAY",""+file.getPath());
            String videoResource = file.getPath();
            Uri uri =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName()+".fileprovider", new File(videoResource));

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
              startActivity(intent);
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this? And is it possible to play a file using the default video player on Android? I tried Google Fotos, Mi Video and the Samsung Video player to play  the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself. The problem was that the apps had no permission to read the URI. Therefore I just needed to add the flag `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.
So you need to change the line
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

to

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```